# PHP - Splitting array (name and value) into different strings?

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => hejsan
    [lastname] => du
)
```

I'm trying to loop through every item in the array, and store the name of the item in the array, and the value of that item, in two seperate strings.

Something like this:

```
$name1 = "name";
$value1 = "hejsan";

$name2 = "lastname";
$value2 = "du";
```

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through the `key=>value` pairs of an associative array:

```
foreach ($array as $key=> $value) {
  // Set the strings here
}
```

However, have you considered how you're going to store these string values as variables? You will either need to use [dynamically named variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which are (imo) messy, or you will want to use two arrays to store the keys and values anyway. If you're just going to use two arrays, you may as well take advantage of PHP's inbuilt array functionality:

```
$array = // your associative array
$arrayKeys = array_keys($array); // the keys
$arrayValyes = array_values($array); // the values
```

So, with this, `$name1` would be `$arrayKeys[0]`, `$value1` would be `$arrayValues[0]`, and so on. Note that yes, this **may** (I don't know how `array_keys`/`array_values` are implemented) be less efficient than a single loop through, but unless your array is **massive** that is not going to be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $keyname => $data) {
// Do whatever
}
```